# Spring Boot Application - Calling service classes

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring and Java and am trying to build a simple REST app that takes in an address string, parses it and tries to verify it.

My main project directory looks something like this:

```
config  
controller
exception
geocoder
model
repository
service 
Application.java
```

As I am writing the app, I have a need to call the service from outside the controller - in the geocoder module. Is this okay in practice? Would I annotate the class inside the geocoder module with an @Component?

Also, You can take a look at my code here: https://github.com/taurenk/PinPointGeocoder2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

The class inside the Geocoder package has to be annotated with @component.

You also need to have the variable that references the Geocoder class [in my case in the controller] with the @Autowired annotation.

This will help Spring know what classes to manage/call.